# Windows 7 December 2018 Security Rollup fails with error 8000FFFF

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Has anyone successfully installed the Windows 7 December 2018 Security Rollup? On **three** different computers it fails for me with the exact same error: 8000FFFF. I've tried renaming the SoftwareDistribution folder to no avail. I also ran an SFC scan which came back clean. At first I thought it might have something to do with the computers being dual-booted with Linux (and thus the Windows bootloader was replaced with GRUB) but it just now failed on another computer that is not dual-booted...

All three machines have been clean-installed within about 1.5 years, and I don't do anything screwy to them that would mess anything up so I'm totally stumped on this one.

Anyone have some ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: @Ramhound I fixed it, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out MS screwed up something and KB3177467

> [image]

never showed up in Windows Update. After manually downloading it from the online Update Catalog and installing it, the December 2018 Security Rollup installed successfully.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "Microsoft screwed up" if the patch summary clearly. indicates the monthly security update should be installed after the SSU  It is important to note, the monthly update the summary is referring to is actually the October monthly security update, not the December monthly security update.  However, due to the October monthly security update being included in the December update, it still applies (which is the reason keeping track of SSUs is important).

Comment: @Ramhound well but the point is the SSU never showed up in the Windows Update client.